# android radio stream phone state speaker

Tags: android, stream, speaker, internet-radio

I develop basic radio stream application with service.After incoming call , radio stream continue but sound play top speaker.I want to play it from all speaker.How to do this ?

Comment: You should show some code, otherwise we wont be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final PhoneStateListener phoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {



@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    try {
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: {
            //PAUSE
            if(BackgroundAudioService.mediaPlayer!=null){

                BackgroundAudioService.mediaPlayer.pause();}
            Log.i("pause","pause");
        break;
        }
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: {

        break;
        }
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: {
            //PLAY
            if(BackgroundAudioService.mediaPlayer!=null){
                BackgroundAudioService.mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);                   
                BackgroundAudioService.mediaPlayer.start();
                Log.i("play","play");
                }               
        break;
        }
        default: { }
        }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

    }
};
```